# React - click event triggers all siblings at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How could I have each `<li />` that receives an `onClick` event to only fire individually **one at a time**?

My intent is to change colors and show/hide content based on a click event. It works, However upon clicking on a given `<li/>` **all** of its siblings get fired at the same time as well.

How could I prevent that?

[here's sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/qv4n8l452q)

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Market />
    </div>
  );
}

class Market extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isColor: false,
      isShow: false,
      fruits: ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach"]
    };
  }

  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState(currentState => ({
      isColor: !currentState.isColor,
      isShow: !currentState.isShow
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const fruits = this.state.fruits.map((item, i) => (
      <li
        key={i}
        className={this.state.isColor ? "blue" : "red"}
        onClick={this.handleToggle}
      >
        {item}
        <span className={this.state.isShow ? "show" : "hide"}>Show Text</span>
      </li>
    ));
    return <ul>{fruits}</ul>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<li>`s are not all firing.
All of your elements are checking state to see if color and visible is true.
So you have one state, for three elements, when one is true, they all are true.

You either want to make an object in the state for each fruit, or better yet, create a new component for the list items that each have their own state, and pass the fruit name through a prop.

I've forked your sandbox and created a quick [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qkmmj7k80j) of what this looks like. This is a core react concept of breaking things out into reusable modules, and having components manage their own state when possible. It will really benefit you in the long run to really get this idea down now, so I hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please show me an example of your latter suggestion?

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm baby stepping into React and will pursue that understanding of modularity and passing props within components as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

All the click handlers are not fired simultaneously, but you keep one variable to indicate if all of them are shown or not.

You could instead keep an object in your state in which you keep key-value pairs indicating if an item is shown or not.

**Example**

```js
class Market extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fruits: ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach"],
    isShown: {}
  };

  handleToggle = item => {
    this.setState(currentState => ({
      isShown: { ...currentState.isShown, [item]: !currentState.isShown[item] }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.fruits.map((item, i) => (
          <li
            key={i}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: this.state.isShown[item] ? "blue" : "red"
            }}
            onClick={() => this.handleToggle(item)}
          >
            {item}
            <span
              style={{
                display: this.state.isShown[item] ? "inline-block" : "none"
              }}
            >
              Show Text
            </span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Market />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll study and learn your solution as well. I wasn't familiar with the `[ ]` notation for accessing state ie: `this.state.isShown[item] `

Comment: @NullisTrue You're welcome! It's a combination of [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and getting and setting a property dynamically with a string.

Comment: @Tholle creating a different component for every `li` element with its own state, Is this approach costly compared to your approach?

Comment: @Vivek The difference in performance is most likely negligible. You can choose what it most readable and fits best for your use case.

Comment: @Tholle in your example, How could I lift the state up as you did plus handle the click events on a child component i.e `<List/>` passed down as a prop? In other words, How could we accomplish the same by lifting the state and making the child a controlled component by its parent? Thank you 

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working sandbox for the approach suggested by @SpeedOfRound. Creating an independent component for every `li` so that that elements has its own state. I don't know this approach is efficient compared to the answer by @Tholle.

SandBox [ https://codesandbox.io/s/1vyonx0zrl ]

Comment: What Tholle suggests is perfectly viable for this example, but it does not scale well. If you were to manage 1000 fruits with 150 different properties each it would become unsustainable. Doing it this way is just better practice.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks, @SpeedOfRound